# Comparing Returns on a Sector Basis

Tags: portfolio, returns

I'd like to compare the returns of a portfolio segregated by groups to the returns of those groups in total.  So say for example I have a portfolio with 40% Industrials and 60% Technology, then over the the same period the returns of Industrials and Technology were 5% and 10%, respectively.

How can I get some idea of the performance of the portfolio?  Or just some ideas on how to measure the performance of a portfolio.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, your question simply boils down to arithmetic as you have the portfolio allocation and sector returns explicitly identified:

Portfolio Return = (Sector 1 Allocation) * (Sector 1 Return) + (Sector 2 Allocation) * (Sector 2 Return) + ... + (Sector n Allocation) * (Sector n Return)

Where the allocations among n sectors add up to 100%.

Comment: Well the portofolio allocation have to be those of the start of the period on which returns have been calculated. @phlsmk I'm also missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

Portfolio's return minus the return of a hypothetical tech and industrials portfolio with market weighting. For example, if the total market cap of the industrial sector is twice that of tech then a two sector portfolio using market relative weights would be 66.67% industrials and 33.33% tech.

If you are investing in all sectors then it is as trivial as subtracting the market return from your portfolio's return. This, however won't tell you what, if any alpha you've achieved.